# Using Java ProcessBuilder to call node module installed globally

Tags: java, node.js, batch-file, npm

I have a node module installed globally: `rollup` but could be any other module. If I open the command prompt(win 10) and type `rollup -v` it returns the module version. I'm trying to achieve this using `ProcessBuilder` / `Process` in java.

Here is my java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("rollup","-v");
File log = new File("log.txt");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));

Process p = pb.start();
assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

It returns the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rollup": CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

If I test it with `java -version` or `node -v` it's working.

I have a working solution but I don't like it and it's a little messy. I create a bat file:

```
//test.bat
rollup -v
```

Then I run the bat file `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.bat");` and is working, but in the future I want to pass other parameters to `rollup` and I don't want to create a different bat file for every parameter.

I think I'm missing something and I don't know what? I'm new to process api.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution for your first problem, but for your workaround:

You can change `test.bat` to `rollup %*` and call it with parameters.

In this case `%*` stands for all parameters that were given to the batch-file. With that you could call it from your program with different parameters as needed.